# How do I get VS Code to recognize CTRL+SHIFT+H?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VS Code <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> keyboard shortcut to find and replace in files is not working for me.

This is the Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting output:

For <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (which does not work):

```
[2022-01-28 12:23:08.659] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-01-28 12:23:08.678] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-01-28 12:23:08.678] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-01-28 12:23:08.886] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
[2022-01-28 12:23:08.886] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
[2022-01-28 12:23:08.886] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-01-28 12:23:09.240] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

For <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (which works properly):

```
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.382] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.382] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.382] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.558] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.558] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.559] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.858] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: KeyF, keyCode: 70, key: F
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.858] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: KeyF, keyCode: 36 ('F')
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.859] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+shift+F
[2022-01-28 12:20:28.859] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 3 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.findInFiles, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
[2022-01-28 12:20:29.069] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (which works properly):

```
[2022-01-28 12:18:08.821] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-01-28 12:18:08.822] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-01-28 12:18:08.822] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-01-28 12:18:09.054] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyH, keyCode: 72, key: h
[2022-01-28 12:18:09.054] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyH, keyCode: 38 ('H')
[2022-01-28 12:18:09.054] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+H
[2022-01-28 12:18:09.055] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 3 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.startFindReplaceAction, when: editorFocus || editorIsOpen, source: built-in.
[2022-01-28 12:18:09.346] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

For some reason the <kbd>H</kbd> key is completely ignored if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> are already pressed.

Comment: Do you have anything else bound to `Ctrl+Shift+H` ?  If you press those keys in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` editor with the `Record Keys` (the little keyboard icon to the right) enabled do you see `Search: Replace in Files` and/or anything else?

Comment: When I do this I see "ctrl+shift", as though I'm not pressing the H key.

Comment: And the H key works normally in an editor?

Comment: Yes. Also with Record Keys enabled I can see "ctrl+h" if I press Ctrl+H and "shift+h" if I press Shift+H.